# i need to replace both wheels on a Giant Escape3 which are compatable?

Tags: wheels

I need to replace both wheels on my Giant Escape 3 (2016) which ones (700) are compatable?

Comment: In general you need to match rim diameter, braking type (disk or rim), hub lengths, type of cluster/freewheel attachment.  Rim width need not be an exact match but needs to be compatible with brakes (if rim type) and whatever tires you plan to use.  Spoke count and arrangement need not match, so long as it's consistent with your planned riding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because needs more information from OP.

Comment: Why can't you get the same size (width/diameter/depth) wheels you have now?   What happened to make both wheels need replacing?

Answer (score 2):

Giant may vary the spec in other markets, but I found this listing:

https://www.giant-bicycles.com/en-gb/bikes/model/escape.3/22033/83618/#specifications

The rim width isn't listed, but [with 32mm tyres, Sheldon suggests 15-19mm](http://www.sheldonbrown.com/tyre-sizing.html).

The gearing on the stock wheel is a 7-speed screw-on freewheel, but getting a wheel with a freehub and a 7-speed cassette should not cause problems.

Without disc brakes, the dropout width could be 130mm or 135mm; as this hybrid looks to be designed more like a mountainbike than a roadbike, 135mm is more likely.